# How to execute function if dropdown value change in edit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I want to use  ng-change directive when user change dropdown value i want to show text area where user can enter the comment, Problem i am facing is when user change value its not showing the text area , once value is selected and click somewhere in the form then it got executed. How i can achieve this when user change current value.
HTML

```
<div class="row">   
        <div class="form-group col-md-6" ng-show="showEditdisForm">
            <div>
                <select kendo-drop-down-list k-data-value-field="'id'"
                    k-data-text-field="'text'" k-option-label="'Select'"
                    k-data-source="ctrlEffOptions"
                    ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                    ng-model="processRating.controlEffectivenessRatingOverrideKey" ng-change="overrideBusinessDec()"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-show="OverrideComments" ng-class="{'has-error': processRatingForm.OverallBusComment.$dirty && processRatingForm.OverallBusComment.$invalid, 'has-success': processRatingForm.OverallBusComment.$valid}">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <textarea rows="2" class="form-control" 
                ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$/"
                required
                id="OverallBusComment"
                name="OverallBusComment"
                ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                data-required-msg="Overall Control Busniess comment is required"
                ng-model="processRating.overallControlEffectivenessOverrideText"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CTRL.JS

```
$scope.overrideBusinessDec = function() {
            $scope.$watch($scope.processRating.controlEffectivenessRatingOverrideKey,function(){
              $scope.OverrideComments = true;
            })
            if (!($scope.processRating.controlEffectivenessRatingOverrideKey == $scope.processRating)) {
              Rating.getProcessRatingFields( $scope.processRating.controlEffectivenessRatingComputeKey,$scope.processRating.inherentRiskRatingKey).then(
                  function(response) {
                    $scope.processRatingFields = response.data;
                    $scope.resetData();
                  })
            } else {
              $scope.OverrideComments = false;
            }
          };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with 
`ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"`
on your select, this tells angular to update your ng-model just after you "clicked out" of the select,
remove that ng-model-options, and this should be fine

Comment: Here is the problem i am facing now if i take ng-model-options off from the select i am not getting the data in the fields

Answer (score 0):

i took off ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" from html and it worked.